# Is it a bad idea to store javascript and css in a database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, css, database

Ok so I'm trying to store user custom css and javascript in mysql database to be used later the head section on the page, so is it a good idea to store css and javascript in a database ? and if not what is the safe way to do this ?

I'm using wordpress and using esc_js() on javascript code I noticed it adds a backslash before quotes, and adds \n instead of new lines, so is it enough for javascript ?

and thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, you do mean CSS/JS that is meant to be used as CSS/JS, correct?  Not user input that is not supposed to, but may, contain CSS/JS?

Comment: yes just plain js/css to be used in the html document.

Comment: You're prone to XCS/CSS  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: Am I prone to XSS by the user or someone else that knows that this database contains js/css code ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. What kind of additional harmfulness do you expect a storage back-end change can add?

Comment: Just want to make if only the user who saves this code is able to do any harm to the site or anyone else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, it's fine as long as it's people you trust.

Long answer:

Make sure you 100% trust your users.  There's a lot of exploits that can be done through CSS/JS, so make sure you're only allowing people you completely trust to do this.  Even if you tried to implement filtering of some kind, people would find ways around.

Depending on how easily you could figure out the file name, I might consider storing the data in a file.  After all, the database is unnecessary overhead if you can readily determine the file name.  If you can't determine the file name easily, I just go ahead and store it in the database.  (Or if you're planning on storing any meta data or version information or anything, I would go ahead and go for a DB.)

Comment: actually only wordpress admin will be allowed to save js/css code.

Comment: Well, hopefully that's people you trust then :)